# Doubts related to a phase plane diagram.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I want to draw phase plane diagram of the following differential equation

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2\frac{dy}{dx} + 10 y = 0.$$

Please check if my approach is correct. I have some doubts about it. They are in **bold**.

First of all I am changing it to a system of differential equation by putting $y_1 = y$, $y_1' = y_2$, $y_2' = 2y_2 - 10 y_1$. So the system of differential equation will be

$$\left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2\end{array}\right]' = \left[\begin{array}{c c} 0 & 1 \\ -10 & 2\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2\end{array}\right]$$

Eigenvalues of the system will be $1 + 3i$ and $1 - 3i$. The eigenvector corresponding $1 + 3i$ is $(1, 1 + 3i)^t$. Computing a few steps we shall get the general solution

$$\left[ \begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{array} \right] = C_1 e^x \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos(3x) \\ \cos(3x) - 3\sin(3x) \end{array} \right) + C_2 e^x \left(\begin{array}{c} \sin(3x) \\ \sin(3x) + 3\cos(3x) \end{array} \right)$$

The system has only one critical point $(0,0)^t$. From the general solution we may say the critical point is a source, as $e^x \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ so the trajectories will spiral out, I am *predicting*.

**How to prove from the general solution that the trajectories will spiral out?**

Let us transform the coordinate system. Transformation matrix will be $T = \left[ \begin{array}{c c} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 \end{array} \right]$. New system of equation will be $$\left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2\end{array}\right]' = \left[\begin{array}{c c} 1 & 3 \\ -3 & 1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2\end{array}\right]$$

Corresponding general solution will be $$\left[ \begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{array} \right] = C_1 e^x \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos(3x) \\ \sin(3x) \end{array} \right) + C_2 e^x \left(\begin{array}{c} \sin(3x) \\ \cos(3t) \end{array} \right)$$

Here it is easy to prove that the trajectories will spiral out.

**Will the trajectories will rotate clockwise or anticlockwise? How to determine?**

I know that if $a + bi$ be the eigenvalue then the trajectories will rotate clockwise if $b > 0$ and anticlockwise if $b < 0$. But $a - bi$ will also be an eigenvalue which can be written as $a + (-b)i$. I am confused.

**Why we are so much interested for the behavior of the system near the critical point?**

Thank you for reading the long question and your help. Is there any short method?

Comment: If possible please draw a phase plain diagram for me using a mathematics software like matlab, C etc. I do not know how to draw them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long story short:** suppose that $\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a} = T^{-1}AT$ where $a,b$ are real numbers.  If $\det(T)$ and $b$ have the same sign, then the trajectory will spiral clockwise.  If they have opposite signs, then the trajectory will spiral counterclockwise.

The system will spiral out if $a^2 + b^2 > 1$, spiral in if $a^2 + b^2 < 1$, and will follow a stable orbit if $a^2 + b^2 = 1$

---

**Full explanation:**

*The below is a work in progress.  However, I thought the above response was helpful enough to merit posting this unfinished.*

The key here is to understand matrices of the form $\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}$.

Let $re^{i\theta}$ be the polar form of $a+bi$. That is, let $\theta = \arctan(b/a)$ and let $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.  We have
$$
\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a} =
\pmatrix{
r\cos \theta & r\sin\theta\\
-r\sin \theta & r\cos\theta
}=
\pmatrix{r&0\\0&r}
\pmatrix{
\cos \theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin \theta & \cos\theta
}
$$
That is, the matrix $\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}$ corresponds, in the standard basis, to a clockwise rotation by angle $\theta$, followed by a scaling by factor $r$.

However, it is important to note that with a different set of coordinates, it may be that this corresponds to a counterclockwise rotation.  For example,
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
\pmatrix{
\cos \theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin \theta & \cos\theta
}
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} =
\pmatrix{
\cos \theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos\theta
}
$$
The trick is that as long as your chosen coordinate system is *right-handed* (that is, as long as $\det T > 0$), $\pmatrix{\cos \theta & \sin\theta\\-\sin \theta & \cos\theta}$ will correspond to a clockwise rotation by $\theta$, whereas if your coordinate system is *left-handed* (that is, if $\det T< 0 $), this will correspond to a counterclockwise rotation by $\theta$.

I hope that helps.

---

For this problem, our ODE was $y' = Ay$, with 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\-10&2}
$$
And you found that 
$$
T = \pmatrix{1&0\\1&3}\implies \\
T^{-1}AT = \pmatrix{1 & 3\\ -3 & 1}
$$
So, in this case, $1$ is our $a$ and $3$ would be our $b$.  We find $\det T = 3 > 0$, which means that $b$ and $\det T$ have the same sign, which means that the trajectory will be clockwise.

Comment: Thank you for answering and elaborating the main problem. In this case eigenvalues are $1-3i$ and $1+ 3i$ and the determinant is 10 > 0. So b = - 3 < 0$. So they have opposite signs. Shall we say the trajectory will rotate counterclockwise?

Comment: I've added a response to your question at the bottom of my answer.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

What you have looks good. Some comments to each of your questions:

Q1/Q2: Your eigenvalues/eigenvectors yield the general solution which you wrote and this tells the tale: you have a complex conjugate pair of eigenvalues (so trajectories *spiral*) and their real part is positive (so they spiral *out*).

Q3: Critical points correspond to the equilibrium solutions of the system. Typically one is interested in how a system responds when it is perturbed from equilibrium.

You might find [these notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PhasePlane.aspx) as well as [this Wolfram Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EigenvaluesAndLinearPhasePortraits/) useful. Here is a rough sketch of the phase portrait for your problem using the latter:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For which solution the diagram is related to? The first solution or the second?

Comment: The entries of the matrix $A$ are displayed to the right of the slider bar: they are the entries of the original matrix you started with.